# Bonded vs unbonded generator when running your main utility panel in an outage

Tags: electrical-panel

I am starting a DIY project, and will be installing a 30 amp inlet on the side of my house for my main panel, with a sliding interlock kit to run my portable generator in the event of an outage.

My panel box is a Square D Homeline, with a neutral-to-ground bond. As I understand it, the rule of thumb is there should be only ONE neutral-to-ground bond present.

I have talked to two electricians at my job, and have been given two different approaches. One says, "Remove the jumper and un-bond your generator's neutral", as I will only be using this generator for the sole purpose stated. The other says, "Do NOT un-bond your generator and leave it as is, it will be fine with both bonded neutrals present." **What is the the correct approach to this?**

My generator also has GFCI protection, so I am unsure about leaving its bonded neutral intact. **Will the circuit protection within the main panel be adequate enough?** I do not want any issues with the gen's bond causing the panel to trip, should I decide to leave it as is. I would also like to add that my house has GFCI outlets.

Comment: What make and model is your generator?  Does it have GFCI protection on its 30A outlet, or just its 15/20A outlets?  Are you OK with only being able to run a subset of your house on the generator, for that matter?

Comment: It is a Briggs and Stratton 5250, and it only has GFCI at the 15/20A outlets. I am trying to keep it simple, and avoid running a floating sub panel, if I can. But if that is the better option, then I will look into it.

Comment: The better option would be to break the neutral-ground bond on the generator.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of that type of interlock, since it is economical and it lets you power any load in the panel, without complex wiring or the need to choose 6 circuits in advance.

> "Remove the jumper and un-bond your generator's neutral"

Correct.

> "Do NOT un-bond your generator and leave it as is, it will be fine with both bonded neutrals present."

Wrong.

It's easy enough to see why.  Your interlock does not switch neutral.  Neutral and ground are connected to the generator anytime it's plugged in, even when you are on "utility" mode.

Normally when an appliance has a problem, it faults current to ground, and that current goes back to the panel, through the one N-G bond to neutral, back to the transformer, completing the circuit. This causes *extremely* high current flow, causing an "instant" (magnetic) breaker trip.

So you have this alternate path for fault current, out the generator's "ground" wire, through its neutral-ground bond, and back the generator's neutral wire.

*Neutral and ground don't have fuses*.

So your electric range has a problem, and has a 2000 amp bolted fault to ground.  2000 amps needs to get back to neutral so it can complete the circuit from the transformer.   It will take all paths between ground and neutral, in proportion to each path's *conductance*.  (1/resistance).  Since the generator is still plugged in, some current will take that path.

It's much worse if the house's normal neutral-ground bond is broken.  In that case, *the long wire run to the generator may not allow the faulty circuit to even flow enough current to trip the breaker!*  The original fault sits there shorting at 65A (within UL spec for a 50A breaker), making LOTS of heat.  Meanwhile the 20A or 30A generator wires are carrying 65A.

Avoiding this kind of uncontrolled event is why you want 1 neutral-ground bond.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth explanation, and clearing up my concern. I will move forward with the removal of the gen's N-G bond.

Comment: #TIL why there should only be 1 N-G bond in a wiring system. Thanks, Harper!